# Как найти дубликаты в списке объектов, отсортировать по полям и оставить нужные?

Tags: java, list, коллекции, java-stream

По итогу сортировки нужно удалить дубликаты с одинаковым именем, оставив имеющего наибольший возраст. Вариант ниже не работает, потому как просто ищет дубликаты, не сортируя. Подойдут любые варианты через циклы или stream API.

```
    People people1 = new People("Ivan", 15);
    People people2 = new People("Petr", 35);
    People people3 = new People("Ivan", 25);
    People people4 = new People("Petr", 30);
    People people5 = new People("Oleg", 25);
    People people6 = new People("Ivan", 20);
    People people7 = new People("Boris", 35);

    List<People> peopleList = Arrays.asList(people1, people2, people3, people4, people5, people6, people7);
    List<People> duplicates = peopleList.stream()
            //группируем в map (пользователь -> количество вхождений)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
            //проходим по группам
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            //отбираем пользователей, встречающихся более одного раза
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
            //вытаскиваем ключи
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            //собираем в список
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для группировки по имени следует использовать соответствующий геттер.

Также достаточно добавить коллектор [`Collectors.maxBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-), принимающего соответствующий компаратор по геттеру для возраста и возвращающего `Optional<People>`, затем *значения* можно преобразовать дополнительным проходом:

```java
List<People> oldies = peopleList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            People::getName, // или People::name в случае record
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(People::getAge)) // People::age
        )) // Map<String, Optional<People>>
        .values() 
        .stream() // Stream<Optional<People>>
        .map(Optional::get) // Stream<People>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Или же можно применить [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-), в котором преобразовать результат `Optional<People>` при помощи ссылки на метод `Optional::get`:

```java
List<People> oldies2 = new ArrayList<>(peopleList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            People::getName, 
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(People::getAge)), Optional::get
            )
        ))
        .values());
```

Comment: Спасибо, комментарии к решению были очень полезны